# Light control using android through wifi on Hardware Board

Tags: sockets, home-automation

I am building a simple android application which can control switching light on and off on a hardware with a wifi connectivity. The board can not create a access point it can only connect to a access point, so I have to use a wifi router to create a access point. Now i am stuck with the problem of how to connect my android device to that board through the access point (wifi router).

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the board a fixed IP address? (192.168.110 for example. Remember that the `Default gateway` is the AP router's IP address). If yes; then you connect to that IP once the Android get connected to the AP Router. If the board has no way of configure a fixed IP address,  then, most of the routers have a `Statistics` page where you can see what is connected and what IP has been given.  Connect to the router admin page and go to `Statistics` page, look for the IP that the router gave to the board.  Use that IP to connect to the board. BTW: Do you know the port number to connect to?

EDIT: AN EXAMPLE

I send you a small method which you can use to connect to that board. Bear in mind that in Android all (most of them) networking stuff should be done in a separate `Thread` o `AsyncTask` otherwise you'll get an exception.

```
/**
 * Connect to the server_IP at the server_Port. 
 * 
 * @param server_IP
 *           host name or IP of the host to conenct to.
 * @param server_Port
 *           port number to connect to that host.
 * @return 
 *  if connection succeded a connected socket; null otherwise.
 */
public static Socket doConnect(String server_IP, int server_Port)
{
    Socket retSocket;
    try
    {
        retSocket = new Socket();
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(server_IP);
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, server_Port);
        // 10 seconds to connect or otherwise timeout.
        retSocket.connect(sockaddr, 10000);
        return retSocket;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: sorry for delayed reply.. regarding IP address yes we have given a static ip address and port number is set as 55555. now after connecting two devices through wifi router, i want to check whether connection is established or not just by pinging to that ip and wait for 10 sec. if no replay came then catch socket timed out exception.